# Python pandas drop_duplicates() inaccuracy

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project that consists of compiling some .tsv files and I am attempting to clean up one of the files and this is what I have so far.

The data file is far too large to paste the output into here so here are a couple photos explaining my current issue.

[before running drop (trying to remove the duplicate tconst)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqoEn.png)

[after running drop (removes way too many rows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7kGp.png)

```
origin = pd.read_table('akas.tsv')

origin.drop(origin.columns[[1,2,5,6,7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
origin.columns = ['tconst','region','language']
origin.drop_duplicates(subset = 'tconst', keep = False, inplace = True) 
print(origin)
```

Comment: Running `drop_duplicates(subset = 'tconst', keep=False)` removes all rows where `"tconst"` has a repeated value, and seems to be working fine to me. What is it that you're expecting as output? (why do you think that it removes "too many rows"?). Also in the future please refrain from posting dataframes as images. Copy/paste them as text into your question.

Comment: keep = 'first' ?

Comment: @CameronRiddell The first output (before drop) has multiple tt0000001, tt0000002, etc. The expected outcome after drop should be to see only one of each, however it seems to drop them all together and starts the table at tt0000019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep one record of each duplicate (instead of all duplicates) you should not use `keep=False`. Citing the [documentation for drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

> keep: {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
> Determines which duplicates (if any) to keep.
> first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
> last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
> False : Drop all duplicates.

By specifying `keep=False` as you have you're instructing pandas to drop all rows that contain duplicates. If, instead, you specify `keep="first"` your dataframe will retain the first entry of any duplicates, and drop all of the rest (which is what it seems like you're expecting).